# Find first occurrence index value in efficent way in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey i have nested list and i wanted find first occurrence index value.

```
data class ABC(
    val key: Int,
    val value: MutableList<XYZ?>
)

data class XYZ(
    val isRead: Boolean? = null,
    val id: String? = null
)
```

I added code which find XYZ object, but i need to find index. So how can i achieved in efficient way. How can i improve my code?

```
list?.flatMap { list ->
    list.value
}?.firstOrNull { it?.isRead == false }
```

Comment: Your code does not find the index at all. It finds the `XYZ` object.

Comment: The index of which list do you want to find exactly? The inner list or the outer list?

Comment: @Sweeper yeah so how can i find index?

Comment: @Sweeper can you tell me both inner and outer list index?

Comment: @Sweeper To be honest i didn't think about that. So could be possible to get both list index value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to stick to functional style then you can do it like this:

```kotlin
val result = list.asSequence()
    .flatMapIndexed { outer, abc ->
        abc.value.asSequence()
            .mapIndexed { inner, xyz -> Triple(outer, inner, xyz) }
    }
    .find { it.third?.isRead == false }

if (result != null) {
    val (outer, inner) = result
    println("Outer: $outer, inner: $inner")
}
```

For each `ABC` item we remember its index as `outer` and we map/transform a list of its `XYZ` items into a list of tuples: `(outer, inner, xyz)`. Then `flatMap` merges all such lists (we have one list per `ABC` item) into a single, flat list of `(outer, inner, xyz)`.

In other words, the whole `flatMapIndexed()` block changes this (pseudo-code):

```
[ABC([xyz1, xyz2]), ABC([xyz3, xyz4, xyz5])]
```

Into this:

```
[
    (0, 0, xyz1),
    (0, 1, xyz2),
    (1, 0, xyz3),
    (1, 1, xyz4),
    (1, 2, xyz5),
]
```

Then we use `find()` to search for a specific `xyz` item and we acquire `outer` and `inner` attached to it.

`asSequence()` in both places changes the way how it works internally. Sequences are lazy, meaning that they perform calculations only on demand and they try to work on a single item before going to another one. Without `asSequence()` we would first create a full list of all `xyz` items as in the example above. Then, if `xyz2` would be the one we searched, that would mean we wasted time on processing `xyz3`, `xyz4` and `xyz5`, because we are not interested in them.

With `asSequence()` we never really create this flat list, but rather perform all operations per-item. `find()` asks for next item to check, `mapIndexed` maps only a single item, `flatMapIndexed` also maps only this single item and if `find()` succeed, the rest of items are not processed.

In most cases using sequences here could greatly improve the performance. In some cases, like for example when lists are small, sequences may degrade the performance by adding an overhead. However, the difference is very small, so it is better to leave it as it is.

As we can see, functional style may be pretty complicated in cases like this. It may be a better idea to use imperative style and good old loops:

```kotlin
list.indicesOfFirstXyzOrNull { it?.isRead == false }

inline fun Iterable<ABC>.indicesOfFirstXyzOrNull(predicate: (XYZ?) -> Boolean): Pair<Int, Int>? {
    forEachIndexed { outer, abc ->
        abc.value.forEachIndexed { inner, xyz ->
            if (predicate(xyz)) {
                return outer to inner
            }
        }
    }

    return null
}
```

Comment: brilliant answer. I want to ask 1st above example for bigger list and `indicesOfFirstXyzOrNull` is for smaller list? Sorry my english is not good.

Comment: can you explain why do use `asSequence` with `flatMapIndexed` and `mapIndexed` what are different ?

Comment: No, both solutions work in a similar way. My guess is that the first may be a little slower, but the difference is very small and not important. The main difference is in the coding style. First uses functional style (so functions like `filter()`, `map()`, `flatMap()`, etc.). This style is often preferred as usually it results in a code that is easier to read. The second uses imperative style (loops, if-else, etc.). In this specific case I think the second is actually easier to read and understand, so I personally would choose it over the first one. But it is really up to you.

Comment: great explanation. Can you please explain `list.asSequence()
    .flatMapIndexed { outer, abc ->
        abc.value.asSequence()
            .mapIndexed { inner, xyz -> Triple(outer, inner, xyz) }
    }
    .find { it.third?.isRead == false }` this in details?

Comment: I added an explanation, but note that if you are not experienced with things like `flatMap`, etc., then it may be hard to digest and fully understand. This is why I added the alternative based on loops - it is probably easier to understand by everyone. Not only by you, but also your teammates who will probably read this code.

Comment: Great answer @broot. Thanks a million 

Comment: one more help can you help me find the last occurrence in the same way in this question. [Last Occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69619927/find-last-occurrence-index-value-of-inner-list-and-outer-list-in-efficient-way-i). Thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, you can use the `indexOf()` function that returns the index of the first occurrence of the given element, or `-1` if the array does not contain the element.

Example:

```
fun findIndex(arr: Array<Int>, item: Int): Int {
    return arr.indexOf(item)
}
```